# Как правильно сверстать таблицы?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы таблицы были по ширине как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался сделать так:

```css
.table {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.table table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table table tr,
.table table th,
.table table td {
  border: 3px solid #4a275c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.table table th {
  color: #4a275c;
}
.table table td {
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>Привод</th>
      <th>Давление [bar]</th>
      <th>Производительность [m³/min]</th>
      <th>Мощность [kW]</th>
      <th>Ресивер [литры]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>ремень</td>
      <td>7,5/8,5/10/13</td>
      <td>6,1/5,9/5,2/4,5</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>шум [db]</th>
      <th>вес [kg]</th>
      <th>Габариты [ДхШхВ]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>900</td>
      <td>1876x1288x1680</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Получается что оба растянуты на 100% родителя. Если не растягивать на 100%, они оба имеют размер меньше нужного.

В общем нужно добиться результата как на картинке. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте дополнительный класс к нижней таблице и укажите размер нижней таблицы отдельно.
Например так:

```css
.table {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.small-table table{
  width: 60%; 
}
.table table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table table tr,
.table table th,
.table table td {
  border: 3px solid #4a275c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.table table th {
  color: #4a275c;
}
.table table td {
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>Привод</th>
      <th>Давление [bar]</th>
      <th>Производительность [m³/min]</th>
      <th>Мощность [kW]</th>
      <th>Ресивер [литры]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>ремень</td>
      <td>7,5/8,5/10/13</td>
      <td>6,1/5,9/5,2/4,5</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table small-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>шум [db]</th>
      <th>вес [kg]</th>
      <th>Габариты [ДхШхВ]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>900</td>
      <td>1876x1288x1680</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов [пример на jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jokeji/edit?css,output):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table table td:nth-of-type(1){
  width: 70px;
}

.table table td:nth-of-type(2){
  width: 100px;
}

.table table td:nth-of-type(3){
  width: 150px;
}

.table table td:nth-of-type(4){
  width: 200px;
}

.table {
  margin-top: 35px;  
}

.table table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.table-s table {
  width: inherit;
}

.table table tr,
.table table th,
.table table td {  
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.table table th,
.table table td {
  border: 3px solid #4a275c;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.table table tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4a275c;
}

 .table table th:last-of-type,
.table table td:last-of-type {
  border-right: 3px solid #4a275c;
} 

.table table th {
  color: #4a275c;
}
.table table td {
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>Привод</th>
      <th>Давление [bar]</th>
      <th>Производительность [m³/min]</th>
      <th>Мощность [kW]</th>
      <th>Ресивер [литры]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>ремень</td>
      <td>7,5/8,5/10/13</td>
      <td>6,1/5,9/5,2/4,5</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table table-s">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TYP</th>
      <th>шум [db]</th>
      <th>вес [kg]</th>
      <th>Габариты [ДхШхВ]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ST 30+</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>900</td>
      <td>1876x1288x1680</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```