# Как сделать таблицу блоками?

Tags: html, css

Собственно нужно сделать 2 адаптивные таблицы как на картинке. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать таким образом, но растянуть всё равно не получается и с бордером беда:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  
}
.table-cel {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cel">1</div>
    <div class="table-cel">2</div>
    <div class="table-cel">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cel">1</div>
    <div class="table-cel">2</div>
    <div class="table-cel">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cel">1</div>
    <div class="table-cel">2</div>
    <div class="table-cel">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Растянуть в каком смысле? последний элемент до конца?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно сверстать таблицы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: Чтобы первая была на всю ширину.
Вопрос не дубликат. В предыдущем вопросе таблица сделана посредством table, здесь - блоками.

Comment: А что Вы хотите растянуть?? Зачем `.table { float: left; }` ?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы растянуть таблицу на ширину страницы, сделать толстую обводку и выровнять текст по центру, добавьте в стиль следующее:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Также нужно будет изменить толщину обводки ячеек таблицы.
Для второй таблицы нужно будет задать желаемое значение width в дополнительном классе.

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно **топорно сделано** , на вторую времени нету делать (на работу пора мне)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
}
.a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.a,
.b {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
}
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.a div:last-child,
.b div:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
.parent1,
.parent2,
.parent3,
.parent4,
.parent5,
.parent6 {
  /*display:inline-block;*/
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent7,
.parent8,
.parent9,
.parent10,
.parent11,
.parent12 {
  /* display:inline-block;*/
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  background: #dddccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a clear">
    <div class="parent1">
      тур
    </div>
    <div class="parent2">
      привод
    </div>
    <div class="parent3">
      давление(bar)
    </div>
    <div class="parent4">
      производительность
    </div>
    <div class="parent5">
      мощность(m3/min)
    </div>
    <div class="parent6">
      ресивер
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b clear">
    <div class="parent7">
      st 30+
    </div>
    <div class="parent8">
      ремень
    </div>
    <div class="parent9">
      7,5/8,5/10/12
    </div>
    <div class="parent10">
      6,1/5,9/5,2/4,5
    </div>
    <div class="parent11">
      30
    </div>
    <div class="parent12"></div>
  </div>
```